# How do I make certain parts of the ChartArea a different color?

Tags: c#, graph, charts

Currently i have this (ignore the text on the top).

[image: graph1]

where i draw the red zone on the bottom with a another Series with the StackedArea chartType and i set all the values to -2. How do i do this the right way where i can manage the "red zones" and place them between any values i want?

here is the code for the chart in the picture http://pastebin.com/vZvjPiQd

edit: whoops, i forgot i had custom classes for creating Controls in the code just delete all the labels and create the Panel manualy with 500x500 size or whatever

Comment: You may use a `RectangleAnnotation` (with proper coordinates, size and color) or (if shape isn't rectangular) another `Series` of type `Range`, `RangeColumn` or `ErrorBar`. As alternative you may use one `StripLine` or your Y axis.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yea it will always be rectangular where exactly do i need to add RectangleAnnotation to always span the whole width of the chart?

Comment: Resize such annotation (yep, has to do it by hand) according to chart client rectangle. Honestly I'd use a StripLine for this (so it'll be tied to specific values instead of pixels).

Comment: `StripLine` is the way to go, as @AdrianoRepetti mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to the solution with this

```
double[] yValue21 = { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
double[] yValue22 = { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 };

series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Range;
series.Color = Color.FromArgb(70, 255, 0, 0);
chart.Series.Add(series);
chart.Series[2].Points.DataBindY(yValue21, yValue22);
```

Comment: Nice. You may want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465005/how-can-i-fill-the-areas-between-two-series-of-spline-or-line/37465012#37465012), more powerful approach..