# How to fill the area between two series in MS Chart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mschart

I am populating chart data under timer `Tick` event:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddY(17);
    Chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddY(10);
}
```

Which generates two series like this:

[image]

I'd like to fill the area between the series like this:

[image]

Here is the designer code for the chart:

```
chartArea1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
this.chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
legend1.Name = "Legend1";
this.chart1.Legends.Add(legend1);
this.chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 339);
this.chart1.Name = "chart1";
series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
series1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline;
series1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
series1.Legend = "Legend1";
series1.Name = "Series1";
series2.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
series2.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline;
series2.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
series2.Legend = "Legend1";
series2.Name = "Series2";
this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);
this.chart1.Series.Add(series2);
```

Comment: Was your goal to draw a black rectangle with two horizontal lines, one red and one cyan?  How do your two chart series, the timer and your black rectangle relate to each other?

Comment: Its not black rectangle, its a chart1 having chartarea1 (with two series) havinf black background, and i am populating data in to chart countineously in timer tick event with inteval 100, and i want to fill transparent color between two series..

Comment: Please share a picture of your expected output. As well as a very basic code to create the chart (including the chart types of the series, ignoring the timer).

Comment: If keeping the bottom area as transparent is not a concern, then you can easily use an `Area` chart and specify the White back color for the bottom series and Blue color for the top series and then it appears like the area between is filled with blue color.

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465005/how-can-i-fill-the-areas-between-two-series-of-splines-or-lines/37465012#37465012)

Comment: @TaW perfect. I could guess you should have already answered something like this. Now  I saw your answer and saw I've already upvoted both question and answer. I'll close this one as a duplicate to keep the other answer as a reference. But I'll keep my own answer here as an example; it stands on its own :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the `Paint` event of the chart and get the points of each series, then create a path based on those points and fill the path:

[image]

[Axis.ValueToPixelPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.valuetopixelposition?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) is the method which helps you to translate series point to paint surface point.

**Example - Filling the space between two series**

The following example, creates two series: `Sin(α)` and `2×Sin(α)` and fills the area between the two charts with Pink color:

```
private void Chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    var points0 = chart1.Series[0].Points.Select(p =>
        new PointF(
            (float)chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX
            .ValueToPixelPosition(p.XValue),
            (float)chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY
            .ValueToPixelPosition(p.YValues[0]))).ToArray();
    var points1 = chart1.Series[1].Points.Select(p =>
        new PointF(
            (float)chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX
            .ValueToPixelPosition(p.XValue),
            (float)chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY
            .ValueToPixelPosition(p.YValues[0]))).ToArray();
    using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
    {
        path.StartFigure();
        path.AddCurve(points0);
        path.AddCurve(points1.Reverse().ToArray());
        path.CloseFigure();
        path.FillMode = FillMode.Alternate;
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Pink))
            e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, path);
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();

    chart1.ChartAreas.Add("A1");
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 90;

    chart1.Series.Add("Sin(α)");
    chart1.Series[0].ChartType =
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline;
    chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Blue;
    chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 3;

    chart1.Series.Add("2×Sin(α)");
    chart1.Series[1].ChartType =
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
    chart1.Series[1].Color = Color.Red;
    chart1.Series[1].BorderWidth = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, Math.Sin(i * Math.PI / 180));
    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
        chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(i, 2 * Math.Sin(i * Math.PI / 180));

    chart1.Paint += Chart1_Paint;
}
```